# Separate jQuery click events

Tags: jquery, click

I a trying to have a div slide out from a hidden position to reveal some toggle buttons and having an issue with the click binding. For the most part it is working but when I click anywhere the clicks are not separated out. When the user clicks on one of the divs, I only want that particular hidden div related to that specific click to slide out. And the user needs to be able to toggle the buttons. Then when they click somewhere else, that hidden div should go away.

Here is the JS and jQuery I am trying and I have to use 1.6.4. I may be able to use 1.7.2 if that would help.

```
//Handle the animation
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(this).click(function(){
  var hidden = $('.hidden');
  if (hidden.hasClass('visible')){
    hidden.animate({"left":"-1000px"}, "fast").removeClass('visible');
  } else {
    hidden.animate({"left":"0px"}, "fast").addClass('visible');
  }
 });
});

//Handle the toggle for click
  function handleBtnClick(event) {
   event = event || window.event;
   var pressed = event.target.getAttribute("aria-pressed") == "true";

   //change the aria-pressed value as the button is toggled:
   event.target.setAttribute("aria-pressed", pressed ? "false" : "true");
    };
  function handleBtnKeyUp(event) {
   event = event || window.event;
   if (event.keyCode === 32) { // check for Space key
    handleBtnClick(event);
  }
};
```

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/S6tQh/2/

Comment: Heavy mixture of JavaScript with `onclick` events and jQuery `.click()` handlers here.. It would be better if you binded these together in one way or another.

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/guGk3/1/ ?

Comment: That's perfect Arun. Is there a way to bind the clicks on the Random Div's (the two main ones in the example) so that when I click on one the other closes/hides?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this

http://jsfiddle.net/LsVQu/1/

Your JQuery code...

```
//Handle the animation
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).click(function(event){
        var el = (event.target || event.srcElement);

        var hidden = $('.'+el.id);
    //var hidden = $('.hidden');
    if (hidden.hasClass('visible')){
        hidden.animate({"left":"-1000px"}, "fast").removeClass('visible');
    } else {
        hidden.animate({"left":"0px"}, "fast").addClass('visible');
    }
    });
});

//Handle the toggle for click
  function handleBtnClick(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var pressed = event.target.getAttribute("aria-pressed") == "true";

    //change the aria-pressed value as the button is toggled:
    event.target.setAttribute("aria-pressed", pressed ? "false" : "true");
     };
  function handleBtnKeyUp(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    if (event.keyCode === 32) { // check for Space key
      handleBtnClick(event);
    }
  };
```

Your HTML code like below...

```
<div class="hiddenleft">
   <div style="float:left">
    <button role="button" aria-pressed="false" class="myButton1" onclick="handleBtnClick(event);change();" onKeyUp="handleBtnKeyUp(event)"></button>
    <button role="button" aria-pressed="false" class="myButton2" onclick="handleBtnClick(event);change();" onKeyUp="handleBtnKeyUp(event)"></button>
  </div>
 </div>
<a href="#" class="slide">
 <div class="right" id="hiddenleft">Some Random Div1</div>
 <div class="clear"></div>
 </a>
<div class="hiddenright">
   <div style="float:left">
    <button role="button" aria-pressed="false" class="myButton1" onclick="handleBtnClick(event);change();" onKeyUp="handleBtnKeyUp(event)"></button>
    <button role="button" aria-pressed="false" class="myButton2" onclick="handleBtnClick(event);change();" onKeyUp="handleBtnKeyUp(event)"></button>
  </div>
 </div>
<a href="#" class="slide">
 <div class="right" id="hiddenright">Some Random Div2</div>
 <div class="clear"></div>
 </a>
```

Your css like below....

```
html {
    max-width: 360px;
}
.hiddenleft {
    float: left;
    height: 75px;
}
.hiddenleft {
    width: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    left: -1000px;
    background: #f90;
    color: #000;
}

.hiddenright {
    float: left;
    height: 75px;
}
.hiddenright {
    width: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    left: -1000px;
    background: #f90;
    color: #000;
}
.right {
    width: 100%;
    float: right;
    height: 75px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
.right:before {
    content: \2605;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
[role="button"] {
 padding:15px 10px;
 border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
 [role="button"][aria-pressed="true"] {
 border: 2px solid #000;
}
h1.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
ariaButton {
    background: #FFFFE0;
    color: #FFFFE0;
    border: none;
}
#ariaButton {
    position: absolute !important;
    clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 */
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
}
input[type=button] {
    color: #0C0;
 font:2.4em Futura, Century Gothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    font-size: 70%;
    /* ... other rules ... */
    cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=button]:hover {
    color: #000;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255);
}
input[type=button]:active {
    color: #000;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255);
}
#accountName {
    font-size: .5em;
}
#accountName:before {
    content: "\278A";
    color: #000000;
}
.myButton1[role="button"] {
    padding: 15px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 65px;
    height: 75px;
    margin-right: -5px
}
.myButton1[role="button"]:before {
    content: "\2605 Button1NoChange";
}
.myButton1[role="button"][aria-pressed="true"] {
    border: 2px solid #000;
    background-color: #666666;
}
.myButton1[role="button"][aria-pressed="true"]:before {
    content: "\2605 Button1IsChange";
}
.myButton2[role="button"] {
    padding: 15px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    background-color: #0C0;
    width: 65px;
    height: 75px;
}
.myButton2[role="button"]:before {
    content: "\2605 Button2NoChange";
    color: #FFF;
}
.myButton2[role="button"][aria-pressed="true"] {
    border: 2px solid #000;
    background-color: #F00;
}
.myButton2[role="button"][aria-pressed="true"]:before {
    content: "\2605 Button2IsChange";
}
```

Try this may be work for you...

Comment: @isaacweathers Could you please try my updated JSFiddle... ` http://jsfiddle.net/LsVQu/1/ `

Answer (score 1):

#### Please try this code :

```
//Handle the animation
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
    if ($('.hidden').hasClass('visible')){
        $('.hidden').animate({"left":"-1000px"}, "fast").removeClass('visible');
    }
    });

        $('a').each(function(event){

            $(this).click(function(event){
             var hidden = $(this).prev('.hidden');
                 event.preventDefault();
                if (hidden.hasClass('visible')){
                    hidden.animate({"left":"-1000px"}, "fast").removeClass('visible');
                } 

                else {
                    hidden.animate({"left":"0px"}, "fast").addClass('visible');
                }
                event.stopPropagation();
            })
        })
});

//Handle the toggle for click
  function handleBtnClick(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var pressed = event.target.getAttribute("aria-pressed") == "true";

    //change the aria-pressed value as the button is toggled:
    event.target.setAttribute("aria-pressed", pressed ? "false" : "true");
     };
  function handleBtnKeyUp(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    if (event.keyCode === 32) { // check for Space key
      handleBtnClick(event);
    }
  };
```

Comment: That's close but it is working backwards. When I click on the toggle buttons they hidden div closes (the one containing the buttons). When I click on the regular divs they stay open. I'm trying to get the opposite effect when I click on the toggle buttons the hidden div would still persist and would only go away when another static div is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use below code :

```
//Handle the animation
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
    if ($('.hidden').hasClass('visible')){
        $('.hidden').animate({"left":"-1000px"}, "fast").removeClass('visible');
    }
    });

    $('button').click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
    })

        $('a').each(function(event){

            $(this).click(function(event){
             var hidden = $(this).prev('.hidden');
                 event.preventDefault();
                if (hidden.hasClass('visible')){
                    hidden.animate({"left":"-1000px"}, "fast").removeClass('visible');
                } 

                else {
                    hidden.animate({"left":"0px"}, "fast").addClass('visible');
                }
                event.stopPropagation();
            })
        })
});

//Handle the toggle for click
  function handleBtnClick(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var pressed = event.target.getAttribute("aria-pressed") == "true";

    //change the aria-pressed value as the button is toggled:
    event.target.setAttribute("aria-pressed", pressed ? "false" : "true");
     };
  function handleBtnKeyUp(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    if (event.keyCode === 32) { // check for Space key
      handleBtnClick(event);
    }
  };
```

Comment: It is working when I click away from the divs. Those two main divs still seem to be bound. That was what was throwing me off initially. Maybe I need to bind each div id to a unique function.